# Mysterious "undefined" associated with keyword this

Tags: javascript

I just started JS and am baffled as to why when object `blackie` eats, instead of seeing the name of the object display, the result is as follows:

> undefined is eating

I assume that the name does not appear because `this` is undefined. Can someone please enlighten me as to how this happened?  I do not understand what the problem is since the below constructor returns an `animal` object.

```
function Animal(name) {
    let animal = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
    this.name = name

    return animal
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log(this.name +" is eating.")
}
let blackie = Animal("Blackie");
console.log(blackie.name);
blackie.eat();
```

Comment: `this` is determined by how you call the function, which you're not doing in the example, so it's hard to know what the problem is.

Comment: You have to make an instance first - please edit that into your question. I cannot reproduce with `const foo = new Animal('foo'); foo.eat()` - it logs as expected

Comment: The code in the question *does not produce the alleged error*

Comment: You haven't showed us how you actually got the error. What code did you run to get this error?

Comment: You're calling `Animal` as a function, so `this` is the same as `window`. Good first-question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to be able to create an instance of Animal with or without the `new` keyword you can simply check if `this` is an `instanceof Animal` - if not, then `return new Animal(name)` like so

```js
function Animal(name) {
  if (!(this instanceof Animal)) {
    return new Animal(name);
  }
  this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is eating.")
}
// using new
let an1 = new Animal('bear'); an1.eat();
// not using new
let an2 = Animal('giraffe'); an2.eat();
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I think i get it now. unfortunately i couldn't edit to correct my question to show in the code what i'm trying to ask.

Comment: @JoshPark - why not? is the edit function not available to you?

Comment: i can't edit my original question. as there's no edit function available. sorry i'm knew to this stack overflow community. i wanted to change the code so that it could return the actual result i'm getting if "run code snippet" is executed.

Comment: @Josh There is an "edit" link underneath the tags. Or, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55671190/edit) (which is the same link that I copied).

Comment: Hi @ Cody Gray thanks, for pointing this out. your changes is on point.

Answer (score 0):

The updated code that the OP posted  presents an excellent opportunity for some pragmatism, as follows:

```js
Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
    console.log(this.name +" is eating.");
}

function Animal(name) {
    let animal = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
    animal.name = name;
    return animal;
}

 
let blackie = Animal("Blackie");
console.log( blackie.name);
blackie.eat();
```

The altered code uses the newly created animal object to attempt to access its own name. The keyword `this` in the prototype now refers to a valid object and so its name property is accessible, yay!

However, there is another way to fix the code as follows:

```js
function Animal(name) {
    Object.create(Animal.prototype);
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

Animal.prototype.eat = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is eating")
}
let blackie = new Animal("Blackie");
console.log(blackie.name);
blackie.eat();
```

Object.create() will create an object

> ...using an existing object as the prototype of the newly created
>   object.

See more info [here](http://The%20Object.create()%20method%20creates%20a%20new%20object,%20using%20an%20existing%20object%20as%20the%20prototype%20of%20the%20newly%20created%20object.).

Essentially, this example needs "new" to instantiate an Animal object and so that it may `return this` in the constructor. Note: the keyword  `this` refers to the instantiated object.(Incidentally, you may ignore the keyword "new" if you alter the code to follow the suggested technique of  @Jaromanda.)

Since it is handy to use Object.create() to create an object based off another one, the following shows another way that the **blackie** object can result in such a case, as follows:

```js
const another_animal = {
  name: "nobody",
  activity: function() {
    console.log(`${this.name}` + " is napping");
  }
};

const blackie = Object.create(another_animal);
blackie.name = "Blackie";
blackie.drink = function() {
  console.log(`${this.name}` + " came, he saw, he drank");
};

console.log(blackie.name);
blackie.drink();
blackie.activity();
```

So, you may also omit the "new" keyword if you base the code on that of an  *existing* object as illustrated in this example. Note that the `blackie` object extends **another_animal** on which it is based.